# Golang transaction exit handling

Tags: go, transactions, sqlx

I have a system with about 100 req/sec. And sometimes it doesn't respond until I restart my go program. I found out that this is because I open transaction and don't close it in some places. That's why all connections were occupied by opened transactions and I couldn't open another one After this I added this code

```
defer func() {
if r := recover(); r != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    return
}

if err == nil {
    err = tx.Commit()
} else {
    tx.Rollback()
}
}()
```

This made my program work for a month without interruption. But just now it happened again. Probably because of this issue. Is there a better way to close transaction? Or maybe a way to close a transaction if it was open for 1 minute?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Also, just a sidenote, but `Rollback` can also return an error, so you should be handling that.

Comment: @MahlerFive, I am not sure yet, it panics and causes the execution to stop. Yes, I know that Rollback and Commit also returns errors, but I don't know how to handle them

Comment: Can you post your whole function?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to roll back the transaction after 1 minute, you can use the standard Go timeout pattern (below).

However, there may be better ways to deal with your problems. You don’t give a lot of information about it, but you are probably using standard HTTP requests with contexts. In that case, it may help you to know that [a transaction started within a context is automatically rolled back when the context is cancelled](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.BeginTx). One way to make sure that a context is cancelled if something gets stuck is to give it a [deadline](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithDeadline).

---

> Excerpted from [Channels - Timeouts](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006221636/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/go/1263/channels/6050/timeouts#t=201710062216368423429). The original authors were [Chris Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670047/chris-lucas), [Kwarrtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725625/kwarrtz) and [Rodolfo Carvalho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4804690/rodolfo-carvalho). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/6050). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 1263 and example ID: 6050.

**Timeouts**

Channels are often used to implement timeouts.

```
func main() {
    // Create a buffered channel to prevent a goroutine leak. The buffer
    // ensures that the goroutine below can eventually terminate, even if
    // the timeout is met. Without the buffer, the send on the channel
    // blocks forever, waiting for a read that will never happen, and the
    // goroutine is leaked.
    ch := make(chan struct{}, 1)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        ch <- struct{}{}
    }()

    select {
    case <-ch:
        // Work completed before timeout.
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        // Work was not completed after 1 second.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of using it? I didn't find anything on the internet

Comment: Examples showing how to use Context are available on the Golang blog (https://blog.golang.org/context) and the Context package itself is well documented (https://golang.org/pkg/context/).